# Nested list getter and setter c#

Tags: c#, list, nested, getter, setter

I have this nested list :

```
 public List<List<string>> pcList = new List<List<string>>();
```

How can I create getters and setters for it?
I have tried everything out there on the internet and nothing seems to work

Thx!

EDIT: 
So, In class Pc I have this code:

```
 class PC
{
    public List<List<string>> pcList = new List<List<string>>();
    public List<string> subList = new List<string>();

  }
```

so the pcList is the "parent" list and the sublist is actually the place where I add each pc with its info.
I have a method where I populate the lists. Then I want to use an object of this class in another class called X, let's say.
I have tried to simply access the lists by using object.ListName but it doesn't work.

Comment: Still very unclear what you have problem with - can you show code that you want to get working? Also what is the point of adding `subList` to the sample - how it is related to `pcList`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use auto property - just add `{get;set;}` (note that usually properties are upper case)

```
 public List<List<string>> PcList {get;set;}
```

Comment: If I do this , I get System.NullReferenceException:

Comment: @alexxa but you've hopefully read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it and now how to deal with NRE already... Clarifying exactly what you have problem with along with your requirements is important to get answer to question *you have* and not one *you wrote*... Consider editing your question to clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: @alexxa `public List<List<string>> PcList {get;set;}` could be `public List<List<string>> PcList {get;set;} = new List<List<string>>();`. This would instantiate the `PcList`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<List<string>> pcList { get; set; } = new List<List<string>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a variable.
If you want a property declare it like:

```
public List<List<string>> pcList {get;set;}
```